# How do I two-way sync recent and most used files to a drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sync

I have an SSD and HDD on my Windows machine:

- SSD: `C:` (OS and most-used files)
- HDD: `D:` (archive files)

There is a lot of trash on `D:`, but some of this trash could be useful in the future, so I keep it on the slower HDD and try to put the most-used files on the faster SSD.

How do I automatically two-way sync files on `D:` to the SSD, but only the most recent files? Let's say the most recent 200GB of files will be synced to SSD; Is there a tool that could work in the background with light load efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

[**`RoboCopy`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) would be one of the most efficient solutions to utilize, but doesn't support copying a specific total size, only individual file sizes

```bat
RoboCopy "D:\Source" "C:\Destination" /E /MON:1 /XN
```

- Required *(all others explained below `File-Sync.cmd` are optional, yet useful)*:

  - **`/E`:** copy subdirectories, including **E**mpty ones
  - **`/MON:1`:** **MON**itor source; run again when more than `n` changes seen
  - **`/XN`:** e**X**clude **N**ewer files

This monitors the source for any changes and logs whenever a file is copied to the destination:

**`File-Sync.cmd`**

```bat
:: #
               :: #[[---  RoboCopy File Sync Script ---]] # ::

:: #=========================================================================

@echo off

:: # Variables #
:: #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

   :: # Date:
      set Date=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%

   :: # Time:
      :: # Hour:
         set Hour=%time:~0,2%
         if "%hour:~0,1%" == " "  set HH=0%hour:~1,1%

      :: # Minute:
         set MM=%time:~3,2%

      :: # Seconds
         set SS=%time:~6,2%

      set Dtime=%HH%%mm%%ss%

   :: # Directories:
      :: # Destination:
         set Dest=C:\Destination

      :: # Log:
         set LogDir=D:\Source\Logs

      :: # Source:
         set Src=D:\Source

   :: # RoboCopy:
      :: # Log:
         set Log=/ETA /LOG:"%LogDir%\%date%_%dtime%.log" /NP /TEE /TS /V

      :: # Options:
         set Opt=/MON:1 /Z

      :: # What to Copy:
         set What=/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:DAT /E /XD Logs /XN

      :: # Save Job:
         set Save=/SAVE:C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync

:: # Sync ::
:: #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   RoboCopy %Src% %Dest% %Log% %Opt% %What% %Save%
```

- **Date & Time:** *(Locale dependent)*

  - **`%date%`:**  Outputs a date in the following format: `yyyy.MM.dd`
  - **`%dtime%`:** Outputs time in the following format: `HHmmss`
- **Directories:**

  - **`%Dest%`:** Destination Directory
  - **`%LogDir%`:** Log Directory
  - **`%Src%`:** Source Directory
- **RoboCopy:**

  - **`%log%`:** Logging Options, outputs a log file in the following format `YYYY.MM.DD_HHMMSS.log`

    - **`/ETA`:** Show **E**stimated **T**ime of **A**rrival of copied files
    - **`/LOG:`:** Output status to **LOG** file
    - **`/NP`:** **N**o **P**rogress - don't display percentage copied
    - **`/TEE`:** Output to console window, as well as the log file 
       *Helpful if needing to run from a terminal occassionally*
    - **`/TS`:** Include source file **T**ime **S**tamps in the output
    - **`/V`:** Produce **V**erbose output, showing skipped files
  - **`%opt%`:** Copy options

    - **`/Z`:** Copy files in restartable mode
  - **`%what%`:** What to copy

    - **`/COPY:DAT`:** what to **COPY** for files (default is `/COPY:DAT`) 
       *Copy Flags: **D**=Data, **A**=Attributes, **T**=Timestamps*
    - **`/DCOPY:DAT`:** Same as above, except for directories
    - **`/XD`:** E**X**clude **D**irectories matching given names/paths 
       *Required if Log Directory is stored in the Source directory*
  - **`/SAVE`:** **SAVE** parameters to the named job file 
     *Outputs job file to: `C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync.rcj`*

**Run Script Silently:**
**`NoShell-RoboCopy.vbs`**

```vbs
'
            '::[[---  Run RoboCopy File Sync Silently  ---]]::'
'=========================================================================

If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
    ReDim arr(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
    For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
        Arg = WScript.Arguments(i)
        If InStr(Arg, " ") > 0 Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
      arr(i) = Arg
    Next

    RunCmd = Join(arr)
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run RunCmd, 0, True
End If
```

- Execute:

  ```bat
  wscript "C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\NoShell-RoboCopy.vbs" "C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync.cmd"
  ```

**Task Schedule: `File-Sync.xml`** *(runs 30s after user login)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-03-30T13:34:58.952588</Date>
    <Author>Windows\User</Author>
    <Description>Task to synchronize HDD to SSD</Description>
    <URI>\Backup\HDDtoSSD</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Delay>PT30S</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>%WinDir%\system32\wscript.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>"C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\NoShell-RoboCopy.vbs" "C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync.cmd"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```